# Is this a good question for this site?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

I hope this question is good for this site:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/61534/string-interpolation-in-routes-view

If it isn't, is it possible to move it to another site?

Answer (score 10):

> This code actually works perfectly. The only problem is that it matches every web page to my not found page.

If it was working perfectly, then by definition there wouldn't be any problems. In particular, *matching every web page to your not found page* really sounds like a problem.

> ```
> resources :movies, except: [:show]
> ```
>
> It should match the web page to the actual page.
>
> I only have a show.html.erb file in my views folder. That can't possibly be the problem.
>
> Is it possible to use string interpolation on view file names?

You seem to be wondering about possible solutions to your problem. Finding solutions to problems is clearly Stack Overflow material. Code Review is more about finding problems in solutions that may appear perfect to you.

Sometimes it's just a misunderstanding. If there is *really* no problem, and you want a review of your approach, or you want recommendations for a better way, then you can rephrase your question in a way to clarify. Being put on hold doesn't have to be the death of your question: if you rephrase it well it can be reopened.

Comment: "Code Review is for finding problems in your solution." - I feel like that should go on a bumper sticker.

Comment: @RubberDuck: ....not to solve problems that make the code **not working**. These belong to StackOverflow.

Comment: I use "**I don't like what it does**" as "likely not good for CR" and "**I don't like how it does**" as "likely good for CR".

Answer (score 4):

You've said that it works perfectly, but you've also pointed out some flaws.  The one question about using string interpolation is also off-topic.

As such, I *could've* have this migrated to Stack Overflow, but they may have some problems with the topicality (much of the code already works), so I've closed it instead.  You can always post the non-working aspects over there yourself.

Answer (score 4):

#### If you are unsure about question fitting the scope of a site,

Most of the stack exchange sites has chat rooms, you can put the question(whole question) in a [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/) and then ask users in a chat room to see if it will be a good question before posting it.

Here we have the [2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor).

But before all that read the [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), then browse the meta site starting with the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) questions.